# Equation of plane vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently learning about vectors and still in the introduction of vector part.
I'm already lost about what's going on from the lecture, reading a book doesn't really help :(.

---

Now I have a homework and I have no idea how to solve it. Here's the problem:

*Find the equation for the plane that's going through $(-2,1,7)$ and perpendicular to the line:
 $x-4 =2t$,
 $y+2=5t$,
 $z=2t-3$

---

I don't really need you to solve it, instead please explain how can I solve this or please point some link for reference for better comprehension.

Thanks.

Comment: If the plane is perpendicular to the line then the vector $(2,5,2)$ is a normal vector of the plane. This together with the point is enough to get its equation. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plane is perpendicular to the line, then the direction vector of the line, which you can find out looking to the parametric equations given, is normal to the plane. Remember that if $$\pi: ax + by + cz = d $$
then $(a,b,c)$ is normal to the plane. The only think that is left to find is the constant $d$. Use the point given in this equation (you know it must satisfy it, after all it belongs to the plane) to find the missing constant and you're done.

Comment: Is this the correct answer? 2(x + 2) + 5(y –1)
– 2(z –7) = 0, or 2x + 5y – 2z + 13 = 0.

Comment: No. The normal vector should be $(2,5,2)$ or any multiple of that, and your normal vector is $(2,5,-2)$. Look again at my observation about the numbers $a,b,c$ of the general plane equation.

Comment: Does changing  $– 2(z –7)$ to  $+2(z –7)$ would make it correct xD. hehehe

Comment: Actually, it would. But if you don't understand why, it's meaningless :P

Comment: Well you are right.. i dont really understand. i just found a question similar to this and switch the answers with things from my problem (you know what i mean). I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Any vector in the plane must be orthogonal to the vector $(2,5,2)$. Given a point $P = (x,y,z)$, it must satisfy $(2,5,2) \cdot ((x,y,z) - (-2, 1,7)) = 0 $. Open that dot product and see what appears. I hope this helps you understand better.